# iterate through an array of all objs not searching through all

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to iterate through ALL my array of objects and search for a field value via a simple if statement.

The below is what I have but it doesn't seem to be searching through all my obj arrays. I would like to search through all my obj arrays to find instances of where a property is a certain value and display only those objs with the matching vals.

```
$.each(data.arrayofObjs, function (index, item) {

  if (data.arrayofObjs[0].objsIDfield == 3222) {
     window.alert("correct!");

  } else {

  }
});
```

Comment: Nice, where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already passing **index** and **item** to your function then do this:

```
  $.each(data.arrayofObjs, function (index, item) {

    if (item.objsIDfield == 3222) {
        window.alert("correct!");

    } else {

   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the use of iterating through the array if you are always selecting the 1st i.e 0th element.

`data.arrayofObjs[0].objsIDfield`

Change it to

`data.arrayofObjs[index].objsIDfield`